# Salt Python API to run states in minion

Tags: python, salt-stack

Can i run my state using python api ?

salt -N 'test_server' state.sls django this will install django in my test minion

Can i do something like this in python script ?

```
import salt.client as client
c = client.LocalClient()
c.cmd('test_server','django',expr_form='nodegroup',pillar={'status':'TEST'})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, salt Client API can do what you want, your code just need to change a bit:

```
import salt.client as client
c = client.LocalClient()
c.cmd('test_server',  # target 
      'state.sls',    # function
      ['django', pillar={'status':'TEST'}],  # arg for function
      expr_form='nodegroup',  
      )
```

see [Salt Python client API docs](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients/#salt.client.LocalClient.cmd) for more detail

Comment: ['django', pillar={'status':'TEST'}] This given me an error , Is list work like this ?

Comment: @AbhilashJoseph might need put `pillar` to kwarg, like `['django'], kwarg={'pillar': {'status': 'TEST'}}, ...`

Answer (score 0):

The Updated code should be

```
import salt.client as client
c = client.LocalClient()
c.cmd('test_server',  # target 
  'state.sls',    # function
  ['django'],  # arg for function
  expr_form='nodegroup',
  kwarg={'pillar':{'status':'TEST'},}
  )
```